# import error when organizing django models in sperate files

Tags: django, model

Following [the django docu](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#organizing-models-in-a-package) I wanted to seperate my models into different files model1.py and model2.py. I also imported both of them in the `__init__.py`. But because they have a relationship, I need to import each of them in the other file. Now I get an error for `from .model1 import Model1` that says

> ImportError: cannot import name 'Model1'

is there a problem because I want to import within model2.py a class from  model1.py that itself is importing from model2.py?

You might say, separating each model in a different file is normally not done in django. But I think it would be much better arranged when you have one file for one model.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Circular Imports Motivation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52700758/circular-imports-motivation)

Answer (score 0):

This caused because of circular imports. `from a import b` and `from b import a`!. Please remove that by splitting the models properly.

Comment: I also assumed that it is something like that, but the question is how I can separate and import them properly? Or is it not possible to put models with a many-to-many relationship into separate files?

Comment: I'd recommend putting them both in the same file. But also take a look at the duplicate link in your OP.