# Circular Imports Motivation

Tags: django, django-models

I have a problem understanding why Django/python doesn't allow circular imports. Is there any way around it without using `apps.get_model` and then hardcoding the label and name of the model?

Supposing I have 2 models `A` and `B` where `A` has a FK to `B` and `B` has some properties based on `A`.

**model `A`**

```
from main import B
field = models.ForeignKey(B, default=None)
```

**model `B`**

```
 # from main import A // this does not work
  @property
    def last_used(self):
        A = apps.get_model(app_label='main', model_name= 'A')
```

The only way to go around it is the code above, if i try to import `A` and use `A.objects.filter` I get `ImportError: cannot import name`error.

My problem is when I refactor the code, it becomes a hassle to look for all those hardcoded model names.

Is this a bad design and I should completely change the logic behind my models?

Comment: It is Python that does not allow circular imports.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem same question then

Comment: To answer your question it would be good if you post more of your code. With this littel information nobody knows what you intend to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need to import A at all inside B. Since A has a ForeignKey to B, you can use the *reverse relation*:

```
@property
def last_used(self):
    return self.a_set.last()
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much, you saved my day and my future ones!

Answer (score 3):

Python does not allow circular imports, since it causes trouble. If you write:

```
# module2.py
import module
```

Python will first read `module.py` and define classes, functions, etc.

But if in `module` it says:

```
# module.py
import module2
```

Then this can not be resolved: since `module2` first needs `module`, and `module` first needs `module2`.

Since it happens often that with `ForeignKey`s such circular imports are required, Django has however added a convenient way to specify models: you can use *string literals*. For example:

```
# app1/models.py

class Model1(models.Model):
    model2 = ForeignKey('app2.Model2', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

whereas in `app2/models.py` we can write:

```
# app2/models.py

class Model2(models.Model):
    model1 = ForeignKey('app1.Model1', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

So you do *not* need to import the models, you can use an string literal that acts as an identifier, and Django will "tie the knot".

In case you need circular references, you can make an import *in* a function, like:

```
def some_module(args):
    from main import A
    # ...
    pass
```

This will *not* result in a circular import (unless you immediately *call* the function of course), since then the `import` is postponed *until* you execute the function.